# Problem extracting variable importance values from Random Forest model (categoric variables)

Tags: r, model, random-forest, r-caret, categorical-data

I'm repurposing a Random Forest script a colleague wrote to run 100 iterations of a model using spatial variables and the caret package, but the script was not originally written with categorical data in mind.

Here is what my data looks like

```
head(sites)
           ID pres         X        Y     depot drainage   slope    elev      dtw
326670 326691    N -69.49958 47.19158 organique        2 2.53601 531.158  964.924
326847 326868    N -69.49959 47.19234 organique        2 5.52269 537.243  993.961
326848 326869    N -69.49849 47.19235 organique        2 3.69843 532.730 1071.810
327027 327048    N -69.49961 47.19309 glaciaire        4 6.70578 546.146 1028.870
327028 327049    N -69.49850 47.19310 organique        2 6.47242 540.644 1104.400
327029 327050    N -69.49739 47.19311 organique        2 3.19070 539.575 1179.800
```

I'm trying to predict "pres" (Y or N, factor). In the variables, "depot" is a factor with 6 levels.

I create a matrix to extract variable importance at each run

```
col_var_imp <- c("depotfluviatile", "depotfluvio-glaciaire", "depotglaciaire", "depotlacustre", "depotorganique", "depotpente", "drainage", "slope", "elev", "dtw")

table.perf <- data.table(iteration = integer(), model = character(), n = integer(),
                         accuracy = numeric(), oob = numeric(), 
                         nn = integer(), ny = integer(),
                         yn = integer(), yy = integer())

varimps <- mat.or.vec(100, 10)
colnames(varimps) <- sort(col_var_imp)
varimps[varimps == 0] <- NA
```

The columns of the `varimps` object are based on a vector i created listing the categories of "depot" as singular "dummy" variables.

```
for (m in c("RF")) {      # m = method used: RF, GLM
  for (n in c(87)) {       # n = number of pseudo-absences
    for (i in c(1:100)) {        # i = number of repetitions, we chose 100
      cat("Starting run", i,"\n")
      
      presences <- sites[sites$pres == "Y",]
      absences <- sites[sites$pres == "N",]
      absences <- absences[sample(c(1:dim(absences)[1]), n),]
      
      selected.sites <- rbind(presences, absences)
      
      #selected.sites[which(selected.sites == 0)] <- NA
      
      train.data <- createDataPartition(selected.sites$pres, p = .7, list = FALSE)
      
      training <- selected.sites[train.data,]
      testing <- selected.sites[-train.data,]
      
      preProcValues <- preProcess(training[, -c(1:4)], method = c("center", "scale"))
      
      training[, -c(1:4)] <- predict(preProcValues, training[, -c(1:4)])
      testing[, -c(1:4)] <- predict(preProcValues, testing[, -c(1:4)])
      
      # Check for near zero variables
      nzv <- nearZeroVar(training[, -c(1:4)], saveMetrics = TRUE) #if there were some we would have to script in to remove them
      
      if (m == "RF") {
        fitControl <- trainControl(
          method = "cv",
          number = 10,
          classProbs = T,
          summaryFunction = twoClassSummary
        )
        modelFit <- train(
          form = pres ~ .,
          data = training[, -c(1,3,4)],
          method = "rf",
          #tuneGrid = expand.grid(mtry = 2),
          family = "binomial",
          trControl = fitControl,
          metric = "ROC",
          model = FALSE
        )
        
        df <- data.frame(varImp(modelFit)$importance)
        df$Var <- row.names(df)
        r <- df[sort(df$Var),]
        varimps[i,] <- c(r$Overall, rep(NA, 10 - length(r$Overall)))

        names <- rownames(r)
        png(paste0(out.png.dir, "pp", m, "_", n, "_", i, ".png"), units="in", width=11, height=11, res=300)
        par(mfrow = c(4, 4), xpd = NA) #one page only (overwrites) so adjust number according to N variables
        for (name in names) {
          pp <- partialPlot(modelFit$finalModel, training, eval(name), main=name, xlab=name)
        }
        dev.off()
      }
```

The script stops mid Run 1 with this error message :

```
Error in [.data.frame`(pred.data, , xname) : colonnes non définies sélectionnées
```

I tried playing with the line :  `varimps[i,] <- c(r$Overall, rep(NA, 10 - length(r$Overall)))`, but it seems to be missing 1 variable.

the object `df` which is supposed to extract variable importance from the model `modelFit` only extract 9 rows, ommiting one level of the categoric variable `depot`.

I don't understand why this happens and how exactly works the here mentioned line with the rep function.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by missing one variable, but in terms of what the line `varimps[i,] <- c(r$Overall, rep(NA, 10 - length(r$Overall)))` is doing, it was defined as a numeric matrix, so this is just re-assigning a particular row of that matrix with whatever the content of `r$Overall` is, and then filling up the rest of the vector with `NA` values. I.e. if `r$overall` is 2 elements long, then this line will combine those two elements with 8 `NA` values, and replace the `i`th row of `varImps` with that combination

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.